# An interesting question about divisibility by $19$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I came across an intriguing problem about *divisibility* as follows:

> Prove that no matter how many $3$'s are inserted between the two zeroes of $12008$, the new number generated will always be divisible by $19$.

I went like this:

Suppose there are $k$ $3$'s inserted. The new number equals

$120\cdot10^{k+2}+3\cdot(10^{k+1}+10^k+\cdots+10^2)+8\\
=120\cdot10^{k+2}+3\cdot\frac{10^2\cdot(1-10^k)}{1-10}+8\\
=120\cdot10^{k+2}+\frac{10^{k+2}-100}{3}+8\\
=\frac{361\cdot10^{k+2}-76}{3}\\
=19\cdot\frac{19\cdot10^{k+2}-4}{3}$

Clearly it should be a multiple of $19$ since the fraction part can easily be proven to be an integer using *mod*.

I think I did it right, but I also want to know if there exists any other kind of approach, such as *induction* or some *intuitive* thoughts, etc. Cleaner solutions and correction on my solution are also welcomed. Thank you!

This is such an interesting fact to me.

Comment: In this case, I doubt that there is any better/easier way. Congratulations to your solution ! It is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Peter Glad to know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy induction as  $$12008=19 \cdot 632$$ and  $$(120\cdot10^{k+3}+3\cdot(10^{k+2}+10^{k+1}+10^k+\cdots+10^2)+8) \\ -(120\cdot10^{k+2}+3\cdot(10^{k+1}+10^k+\cdots+10^2)+8) \\ = 120\cdot10^{k+3} + 3\cdot10^{k+2}- 120\cdot10^{k+2} \\= 1083 \cdot10^{k+2} \\= 19 \cdot 57 \cdot10^{k+2}$$

so you start with a multiple of $19$ and keep adding multiples of $19$

Comment: This is how I would do it, except instead of factoring the multiples of 19 I would use a divisibility test: add twice the last digit to the remaining digits.  Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can prove this by induction too.

If $A_n$ is the number which has $n$ threes between the two zeros, then it is easy to see that

$$A_{n+1} = \left(\frac{A_n - 8}{100} \cdot 10 + 3\right) \cdot 100 + 8$$

How do you see this? You see it constructively. Think what the first operation $\color{red}{-8}$ does to $A_n$. Then think what the second operation $\color{red}{/100}$ does and so on. You will see that I am really constructing $A_{n+1}$ starting from $A_n$.

If you simplify this you get:

$$A_{n+1} = 10 \cdot A_n + 19 \cdot 12$$

From the last equality it is obvious how one can do the induction.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is easier, but you can do it inductively.

Let $$a_0=12008=632\times 19$$$$ a_n=100\left(\frac {a_{n-1}-8}{10}+3\right)+8=10(a_{n-1}-8)+308=10a_{n-1}+228$$

Noting that $228=19\times 12$ the induction is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Let us find how $3$ has been identified

$$120\cdot10^{k+2}+a\sum_{r=2}^{k+1}10^r+8$$

$$\equiv6\cdot10^{k+2}+a\cdot\dfrac{10^2(10^k-1)}9+8$$

$$\equiv\dfrac{10^{k+2}(54+a)+72-100a}9$$

So, it is sufficient to have $$54+a\equiv0\pmod{19}\text{  and }100a\equiv72\pmod{19}$$

$$a\equiv-54\equiv3\text{ and } 5a\equiv-4\equiv15$$

$$\implies a\equiv 3\pmod{19}$$

For numbers  in base $10, 0\le a\le9$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} n &\,=\,\ \  [a]33\cdots 3308\\[.1em]
\Longrightarrow\ 3n &\,=\, [3a]99\cdots9924\\[.1em]
&\,=\, 3a(10)^k\! \color{#c00}{+ 10^k}\!-76\\[.1em]
&\,\equiv\, (3a\!\color{#c00}{+\!1})10^k\!\!\!\pmod{\!19}\\[.2em]
{\rm so}\ \ 19\mid n&\iff 19\mid 3a\!+\!1\iff \underbrace{a\equiv 6\!\!\!\pmod{\!19}}_{\textstyle {\rm e.g.}\ \ \ a = 120}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: If we replace $\,08\,$ by $\,b\,$ then we get $\, 3n\equiv (3a\!+\!1)10^k+3b\!-\!100,\ $ so $\ 19\mid n\ $ if $\ 19\mid 3a\!+\!1,\,3b\!-\!5,\,$ i.e. if $\,a\equiv 6,\ b\equiv 8\pmod{\!19}$